# Aries jndi lookup in osgi

Tags: glassfish, osgi, jndi, aries

My application has some OSGI modules and an non-OSGI part. I tried lookup osgi services in non-osgi subsystem through JNDI with apache aries. I use glassfish.

My blueprint xml looks like:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
 <bean id="repositoryservice"
  class="com.example.repository.jndi.RepoImpl">
 </bean>

 <service ref="repositoryservice"
  interface="javax.jcr.Repository">
 </service>

</blueprint>
```

I tried a lookup with:

```
Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
Repository repo = (Repository)jndiContext.lookup("osgi:service/" + 
                   Repository.class.getName());
```

I deployed 4 Bundles:

1. Apache Aries Util
2. Apache Aries Proxy Bundle
3. Apache Aries Blueprint Bundle
4. Apache Aries JNDI Bundle

But i get an Exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'osgi:service/javax.jcr.Repository' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: osgi:service]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at com.example.JndiTest.testRepositoryNotNull(JndiTest.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: osgi:service
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.resolveContext(TransientContext.java:310)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:218)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:144)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:174)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
```

Did I forget a bundle? 
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish has it's own JNDI engine while Aries JNDI is a standalone implementation as well.

Ordinary Java EE applications (EAR, WAR, ...) will use the GlassFish JNDI engine. Glassfish JNDI engine does not support "osgi:service". In case your subsystem is an ordinary Java EE application it will not work.

Based on your stacktrace you use the Glassfish JNDI engine.

Aries JNDI is useful in case of the following scenario: You have an existing JAR that has a class that looks up an object via JNDI. The JNDI location can be configured. You add OSGi entries to the MANIFEST.MF and deploy the JAR to the OSGi container. Even in this case you must be sure that your new bundle wires to the Aries JNDI and that the service is registered before the lookup is done.

Comment: How can I register a osgi service which i can lookup in an other JVM without aries? If i register it with the bundlecontext only other bundles can find the service

Comment: Another JVM or in the same JVM but outside the OSGi container? If you are interested about another JVM it can be done only via some remote protocol (RMI, SOAP WS, RESTFul API, ...)

Comment: The remote services chapter of the OSGi Enterprise Specification might be interesting for you. You can find two major implementations: Apache CXF DOSGi, Eclipse ECF. With these two you can expose OSGi services remotely and use those services from another OSGi container. However, these technologies use the mentioned solutions inside (like REST API, SOAP, ...)

Comment: Is it theoretically possible, to use JNDI, to access a osgi service in another JVM?